# Showing if the following function is odd or even

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, even-and-odd-functions

The function $f$ is periodic with $T=2\pi$ and is given as $f(t)=t$ where $-\pi \leq t \leq \pi$
Is $f$ odd, even or periodic or neither? Also, where is $f$ discontinuous?

Normally if a function is even or odd we would plug in f(-t) and see if we got back the exact same function (even) etc, but here it is even with the period $2 \pi$. I wasn't too sure what to do so I instead found the fourier series corresponding to the restrictions above which gave me:
$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\dfrac{2}{n}(-1)^{n+1}\sin{n t}$
Usually, sine is an odd function but I don't think this is the way to determine if $f(t)=t$ is odd or even or neither. Also, where does the discontinuity come into play? My guess is it is discontinuous in relation with its period, not sure if that makes sense but that's my only guess.

Comment: I suggest to draw a graph of the function over the interval $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$. You should see quickly that $f$ is neither even nor odd.

Comment: But isn't f(-t)=-t <=> that the function is odd? And How can y=t be discontinuous?

Comment: Your have $f(t) = t$ only for $-\pi \leq t \leq \pi$. Again, I suggest to sketch the function on a larger interval.

Comment: I figured it out, thank you! It is discontinuous for odd pi, that is, if $k \pi$ when k is odd, I still think that the function is odd because the fourier series is composed of only sines which is a sign that it is an odd function, no?